# Is this a valid way of defining a struct that references a node of the same type?

Tags: c, struct

The structure I want is a linked-list. Each block contains a header and a block_part. The header contains free, prev, and next. I'm just wondering if the code below is a valid implementation.

```
typedef struct block
{
    /*header + block*/
    bool free;
    block *prev;
    block *next;
    char block_part[];
} block;
```

In response to the comments, so the correct way to do this is :

```
typedef struct block block;

struct block
{
    /*header + block*/
    bool free;
    block *prev;
    block *next;
    char block_part[];
} ;
```

?

Comment: Not in C; you need to use `struct block *` inside the structure definition.  Or you need `typedef struct block block;` followed by `struct block { …; block *next; … };`.  The story is different in C++.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question.

Comment: That is one of the two valid ways to do it.  The other was `typedef struct block { …; struct block *next; … } block;`.  Both work.  They're basically equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward declare first ie

```
typedef struct block block;
```

then declare the struct ie

```
struct block {
  bool free;
  block * prev;
  block * next;
  char block_part[];
};
```